# Logstash - Bad event type, Non-string/integer type value set

Tags: java, elasticsearch, log4j, logstash, logstash-grok

I want to send logs from Java app using Log4j to my logstash server over TCP.
Communication between two servers works great but When I receive logs from my Java app, I have an error into logstash's logs file:

```
[2017-04-19T09:15:18,549][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Failed action. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"hadoopws_log-2017.04.19", :_type=>"[\"log4j\", \"001\"]", :_routing=>nil}, 2017-04-19T07:15:18.486Z 10.10.2.100:60283 "ROUM" 8962 001 2 3136 109 3245], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"hadoopws_log-2017.04.19", "_type"=>"[\"log4j\", \"001\"]", "_id"=>"AVuFEL1uRiFXDsNz9hxO", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"invalid_type_name_exception", "reason"=>"mapping type name [[\"log4j\", \"001\"]] should not include ',' in it"}}}}
```

My logstash's config file:

```
input {
    log4j {
    mode => "server"
    host => "hadoopmasterdev"
    port => 3456
    type => "log4j"
  }
}

filter {
   grok {
     match => { "message" => "%{DATA:request} %{WORD:idgroup} %{WORD:type} %{NUMBER:nb} %{NUMBER:process_time} %{NUMBER:render_time} %{NUMBER:total_time}" }
   }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["hadoopmasterdev:9200"]
    index => "hadoopws_log-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

Then, I send those logs:

> "test 1" 28 001 26 33 116 149

When I try to validate my Grok pattern using [GrokDebug](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/), it works well...

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the third field name from `type`to something else, because that interferes with the `type: log4j` field defined in your `log4j` input. As a result, the `type` field becomes an array that contains two values, namely `log4j` and `001` and that cannot be used to define the mapping type in the elasticsearch output.

Simply change your `grok` pattern to this and it will work.

```
grok {
   match => { "message" => "%{DATA:request} %{WORD:idgroup} %{WORD:datatype} %{NUMBER:nb} %{NUMBER:process_time} %{NUMBER:render_time} %{NUMBER:total_time}" }
}
```